# How do I update a progress bar based on a foreach loop that runs based on a variable array?

Tags: c#, foreach, progress-bar

Example:

At this point in my code, the progress bar is at 70:

```
pbUpload.Value = 70;

foreach (string file in finalFiles)
{
    //processes
    //processes
}
```

finalFiles has a VARIABLE LENGTH. Meaning it does not have a fixed number. So basically I need to figure out the number first, which is easy, but then how do I construct a loop in which it'll update the progress bar from 70 to 100 (100 being the last "each" element)?

Comment: What type does the `finalFiles` variable have? `List<T>`?

Comment: Please see my answer. If I understand you right, that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
int count = finalFiles.Length;
int current = 0;
foreach (string file in finalFiles)
{
    current++;
    pbUpload.Value = current / count * 30 + 70;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: if `finalFiles` is a `string[]` as the OP indicated, wouldn't it be better to use `finalFiles.Length`?  Although the difference is trivial since it is an array, there is still less complexity calling `Length` directly

Comment: It's not an array if it is variable length. Or am I missing something?

Comment: OP said in the comments that it was an array

Comment: In any way, my post would work for any IEnumerable. But yes, if it was an array, definitely would call Length.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble with the term variable-length array. There's no such thing.. arrays are fixed..

Comment: @JonyAdamnit... The point is that it's not known *at compile time*.  It's not fixed *until runtime*.  The point being he can't just hard code the step value, he needs to use `Length` or whatever to calculate it.

Comment: Yeah yeah I get it :)   The Length part is trivial, so I don't think it should have been given all this attention in the question body as well.

Comment: I changed finalFiles.Count() to length. and this worked. thx Jony!

Comment: @JonyAdamnit... you are right, it is trivial (which i did say), and either works, but call `Count()` on an array or List<T> or any other ICollection<T> adds unnecessary overhead for a value that can be obtained by checking `Length` (or `Count` in the case of an `ICollection`).. which I am only mentioning for future generations who read this.  But +1 for the answer.... it's a nice simple solution.

Comment: @psubsee2003 you are correct, which is why I edited my answer. BTW, you know why this works yes? (this is for future generations also) It works because current / count is the percentage of what we've done so far.. multiplying by 30 makes it relative to what's left, adding 70 for what was done before :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `BackgroundWorker` for this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown); 
       backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
       backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
       backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += 
       new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
       pbUpload.Value = 70;
   }

   void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
   }

   int val = 0;

   void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       val = (100 - pbUpload.Value) / finalFiles.Length;

       foreach (string file in finalFiles)
       {
           //Your processes
           backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(pbUpload.Value + val);
       }
   }  

   void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        pbUpload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   }
}
```

Comment: never used it. can you give me an example?